# Problem 2.2 Atiya and MacDonald pg.31

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, tensor-products, tensors, exact-sequence

Here is the question:

Let $A$ be a ring, $\mathfrak{a}$  an ideal, $M$ an $A$-module. Show that $(A/ \mathfrak{a}) \otimes_A M \cong M/\mathfrak{a} M.$

And here is its solution:

> [image]

I have some questions about the solution:

1- Why multiplying by $- \otimes_A M$ and not by $M \otimes_A -$? Also, I believe that there is only zero on the right because the tensor functor is right exact and not left exact, am I correct?

2- Is $(A/ \mathfrak{a}) \otimes M \cong (A \otimes M)/ \operatorname{Im}j$  by the first isomorphism theorem? is this because the map on the arrow after the $j$ is surjective and its kernel equals the image of $j$?

3- I do not see how the absorption Isomorphism sends $\operatorname{Im}j$ to $\mathfrak{a} M$?

Could anyone help me in answering those questions please?

Comment: 1. The two are the same (you can easily map $a \otimes b$ to $b \otimes a$). 2. I think it's just by if $A \cong B$, and the image of $I$ is $J$, then $A/I \cong B/J$

Comment: About 3., I dont get the definition of the absorption isomorphism.

Comment: Consider the map $p(m \otimes a) = ma$. Is that an isomorphism? (Hint: think about the map $q(m) = 1 \otimes m$). This is the absorption isomorphism.

Comment: Exact sequence implies $(A \otimes M) / (\mathcal{a} \otimes M) \tilde{=} A /\mathcal{a} \otimes M$. Now use the isomorphism $ \mathcal{a} \otimes M \tilde{=} \mathcal{a} M$. This is what the above comment User203940 is referring to. Note that if $bm = 0$ for $b \in a$ and $m \in M$ then $b \otimes m = 1 \otimes bm = 1 \otimes 0 = 0 \otimes 0$. Note that tensor product is an equivalence class.

Comment: @onriv What about the second part of my first question?

Comment: @User203940 I believe that the absorption homomorphism is not related to Im j being $\mathfrak a M$ (as the author of the answer claimed )..... right

Comment: @Balajisb Is there a source of a proof for your first statement? Also, is there a proof for the isomorphism in your second statement?

Comment: @MathIgnorance i have added an answer for your 3 questions. Cheers !

Comment: In the last statement of your comment ..... are you proving the claim in your second statement in the same comment?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Tensor product is bi-linear and an equivalence class. So right tensor product or left tensor product does not matter as long as you maintain the equivalence class correctly i.e., $m \otimes a = am \otimes 1$.
2. You are correct, since $a \otimes M \rightarrow A \otimes M \rightarrow A/a \otimes M \rightarrow 0$, it is first isomorphism theorem: $(A \otimes M) / (a \otimes M) \tilde{=} A/a \otimes M$.

But you need to verify that $Ker(f: A \otimes M \rightarrow A/a \otimes M) = a \otimes M$ keeping the equivalence class in mind.
$0$ in tensor product is of the form $0 \otimes m = a \otimes 0 = 0 \otimes 0$.
$f(\sum_i b_i \otimes m_i) = f(1 \otimes \sum_i b_i m_i) = f(1 \otimes m')$.
$ f(1 \otimes m') = (1+a) \otimes m'$

$(1+a) \otimes m' = 0 \otimes m'$ implies $1+(a) = 0$ which is not true.
$(1+a) \otimes m' = 1 \otimes 0$ implies $(1+b)m' = 0$ for some $b \in a$. This implies $m' = -bm'$. This implies $1 \otimes m' = 1 \otimes -bm' = -b \otimes m' \in a \otimes M$.
Hence $Ker(f) = a \otimes M$.

3. This is because $b \otimes m = 1 \otimes bm \tilde{=} bm$

Note that i am assuming $1 \in A$ and $1.m = m$.

Comment: But Tensor product is only right exact, right? and that is why we have only a zero on the right ..... right?

Comment: Can u put what you are asking in an equation ?

Comment: I am speaking about the sequence in the fourth line of the answer I posted in my question why it does not have a zero on the left even though the original sequence before tensoring had a zero on the left

Comment: If u r asking why not put $0 \rightarrow a \otimes M \rightarrow A \otimes M \rightarrow A/a \otimes M \rightarrow 0$ then u r correct as $0$ in the left mean injective and inclusion map is injective. But irrespective of whether we put it or not all that matter is $a \otimes M \rightarrow A \otimes M \rightarrow A/a \otimes M \rightarrow 0 $ is an exact sequence and this guarantees that $Ker(f) = Im(j) = a \otimes M$. Check out the definition of exact sequence

Comment: The reason why didnt they put a $0$ on the left is because all we want is $Im(j) = a \otimes M$. We dont care if this map $j$ is injective or not. So for proof, it does not matter. Although i agree with you that putting a $0$ is also correct.

Comment: Further note that i am assuming unit or $1$ element is in the ring $A$ and $M$ is hence a unitary left module. Check out the book if this assumption is true for the theorem you are trying to prove.